# How to remove settings from a Microsoft Account in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-8.1-upgrade, microsoft-account

When installing Windows 8 for the first time, I did not create a Microsoft account, and just installed as the local user.

However I recently updated to Windows 8.1 and it forces you to use a Microsoft account. I did not want to create an account so one of my friends used his and I logged in. After logging in I got all the friend's details like apps, wallpaper, lock screen, search mechanism, and when I use search I see the friend's Facebook friends popping up. It is really annoying.

How can I remove all of this excess, as I have logged out of the Microsoft account and am just using local user, but these problems have persisted?

Comment: There is actually two methods to skip that "required" step.  You can either start to create a new account then hit cancel, or provide invalid information to your `Microsoft Account`, and when authenication fails choose to handle it later.  On the account where you attached that `Microsoft Account` there is a mechanic on the Modern UI PC Settings page that will allow you to disconnect it.  A quick google search can help you locate a visual guide.

Comment: I have logged out of the account, is this idfferent from detaching it? unfortunately I realized too late that it actually could be skipped

Comment: I will have to get back with you on that.  The only thing you can try is delete the (new) user profile that was created to handle the `Microsoft Account` connected account.

Answer (score 0):

Open PC Settings. Go to Accounts > Your account > Disconnect.

Also, Windows 8.1 **does not** require logging in with a Microsoft account, just as Windows 8.0 didn’t (think of all the domain users).

Answer (score -1):

Solution - switch to Linux. Problem solved, but until then download and make a USB or CD boot disc for Ubuntu.

How to help yourself if you get locked out by Windows 8 or 8.1

USE LINUX...

No seriously, assuming you have  another PC to be able to make the live CD or live USB, or you could just install Ubuntu on a second partition as a failsafe...

1. Get a Linux live CD
2. Boot the CD
3. Go to `C:\Windows\System32`
4. Rename `Utilman.exe` file to `Utilman-bak.exe`
5. Now rename `cmd.exe` file to `Utilman.exe`
6. Restart your PC and remove the cd or usb flash drive.
7. Now click on `Ease of access` (left bottom corner of the screen, looks like a pie or a clock to some people) and  `cmd.exe` will pop up.
8. Type `net user`, without quotes in command prompt it will show all users list.
9. Now you have to add a new user so type:

   ```
   net user /add backupuser password
   ```

   Here your new username is `backupuser` and its password is `password`.
10. Now you have to make this user as a administrator ,so type:

    ```
     net localgroup administrators backupuser /add
    ```
11. Restart your PC, and login with your new user: here it's `backupuser`, give the password `password`.
12. Now it’s done. Now you may change your old user account password from the Control Panel by deleting the old account - then you can set it up again and put your old password back. Remember to always back everything up.
13. That's not all, your PC is not yet ready for use, boot with your Linux CD and go to sda search for C:\Windows\System32 folder, now rename “Utilman.exe” to “cmd.exe” and now rename “Utilman-bak.exe” to “Utilman.exe”. Done.

Also go to the UAC and change that as well as the taskbar, right-click and change how it logs you in to your desktop, etc.